# Cómo incluyo mis header y footer a mis vistas?

Tags: php, html, error404

Antes de empezar quiero aclarar que estoy implementando todo esto en una plantilla boostrap 4 llamada Admin SB 2.

En este pequeño proyecto, dentro de mi carpeta principal, tengo mi archivo index.php, dentro de mi carpeta proyecto tengo un directorio llamado vistas donde guardo footer.php y header.php y dentro de mí index.php incluyo footer.php y header.php, por ejemplo:

```
<?php require_once("vistas/header.php") ?>

<!-- INICIO DEL CONTENIDO PRINCIPAL -->

<div class="container">
    <h1>Contenido principal</h1>

</div>
<!-- FIN DEL CONTENIDO PRINCIPAL-->

<?php require_once("vistas/footer.php") ?>
```

Todo excelente hasta aqui, el problema empieza cuando dentro de mi directorio vistas, tengo otro directorio llamado **pacientes** que es donde pienso guardar todo lo relacionado con el modulo de pacientes. Aquí tengo en

```
//header
<?php require_once("../header.php") ?>
//aqui va mi contenido
//footer
<?php require_once("../footer.php"); ?>
```

Entonces, los problemas que me da la consola son estos:

[image: Errores de direccion]

Puedo entender que son errores de la dirección de los archivos necesarios para el diseño y funcionamiento de la pagina, pero si edito la dirección en los archivos header.php y footer.php, puedo resolver el problema de los archivos dentro de directorios en las vistas, pero me dejara de funcionar el index.php.

Que me pueden recomendar hacer?

Pasen feliz resto del dia

Comment: El modulo de pacientes (refiriendome a tus vistas) los archivos los tienes declarado `index.php` o `index.view.php`? Porque si es lo segundo, en tu `index.view.php` puedes cargar el header y el footer. y en tu archivo controlador (o `index.php `) solo agregas la vista.

Answer (score 0):

Algo que te puedo recomendar es crear tu carpetas de vistas con archivos tipo `index.view.php` como buena practica de programacion y, para separar la vista del controlador. supongamos que las ruta de tu proyecto es algo asi:

```
proyecto
  ->views
    ->header.view.php
    ->footer.view.php
    ->index.view.php
    ->paciente.view.php
  ->assets
    ->style.css
    ->script.js
  ->index.php
  ->paciente.php
```

Los archivos header y footer seran usados por ambos controladores sin problema alguno.

`paciente.php`

```
<?php
require('views/paciente.view.php');

?>
```

y en paciente.view.php los agregas

`paciente.view.php`

```
<?php require('views/header.php'); ?>

<body>
   <div class="container">
      contenido de la pagina
   </div>
</body>

<?php require('views/footer.php'); ?>
```